new to OpenCV, how do i install/build opencv_traincascade
So I've been working on machine learning projects, and needed to train a custom dataset using opencv_traincascade. but whenever i tried installing it, it would never work. I got other things like opencv_annotation and stuff to work, but traincascade or event createsamples wouldnt work. Do i have to manually build these?
I downloaded mingw-gcc, cmake and couldnt find a feasible solution online. I have opencv 4.9.0 by the way, installed both on anaconda and in my C: drive manually. I have tried looking for some third parties too, who had the entirety of opencv installed and could be replicated, but no luck. Any help would be severely appreciated, thank you!

opencv_traincascade has been removed since version 4.x, so you have to use opencv version 3.4.x to have opencv_traincascade.
You can use this guide to install opencv_createsamples and opencv_traincascade.
References:

opencv documentation
opencv issues 13231
opencv issues 14322


Thank you! I've tried building it on Python 3.4.1 and it works here. Any clue why it has been removed?

I don't know why it has been removed, but you can pick up the GSoC 2024 proposal for reintegrating this functionality in an updated manner - github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231#issuecomment-464025828
